# Any reason why the AWS SDK for PHP doesn't automatically use NextToken?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

When using the AWS SDK for PHP with SimpleDB (a mouthful) the "select" section of the documentation ( http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonSDB/select ) has the option:

**NextToken - string - Optional - A string informing Amazon SimpleDB where to start the next list of ItemNames**

And provides some helpful code to handle this scenario.

But it seems to me that having to wrap all select statements in code that checks for a NextToken and appends the data is something that should be a basic function of the SDK, maybe as an option: do_auto_NextToken => 1

Am I missing some basic reason this isn't the case?

And can anyone with more familiarity of the SDK tell me where the select handling is being done so I can see if it makes sense to patch the SDK myself to autohandle NextTokens ?

Thanks for your help and opinions!

Tosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the low-level structure of the current AWS SDK for PHP, it probably would *not* make sense to do this since each request returns the whole response as a simplexml object. If the nextTokens were used to make the subsequent requests automatically, it would make it difficult to expose the responses for each of the requests individually in a way that is consistent with how the rest of the SDK works.

That being said, I think what you are talking about would be a great feature of a higher-level abstraction. In fact, the AWS SDK for Ruby is designed solely as a higher-level client, and does process the nextTokens automatically for you. Seeing higher-level clients added to the PHP SDK would be really useful.

Instead of patching the SDK to handle nextTokens, I would consume it by a middle-layer library that your application can use. If you have specific questions about how the SDK works, you could always ask on the [AWS PHP Development Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=80).